# I have been invited to attend Non-Muslim friends marriage?

Tags: nikah, non-muslim

My office colleague is inviting wholeheartedly to his marriage ceremony.
And there will be Music and Dance as well in the ceremony.
He is a Non-Muslim, what should I do in order to make a balance between my Islam and friendship.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. As is written this looks like an advice request, as we are no peer support these kinds of questions are hardly on topic. Therefore I strongly recommend you to edit it to make it go along with the SE policies (also check our [help] for further information).

Comment: What is more important to you,  friendship or your religion? Who do you want to please? Your colleague or Allah(swt) ?  Maybe your colleague will be disappointed when you reject his invitation, but you might be able to explain your reasons for doing so.

Answer (score -2):

Yes and No.

You can go to his wedding but you have to be careful that there might be evil music and evil things there such as Alcohol, bad music, zina and so on. If there there is evil things in it, you can leave the wedding and you cannot congratulate him because of evil things that contain there, if it is free from evil things, you can congratulate him and you can say: “May God give you honor with Islam” and if God wishes he will become a Muslim as you. And if he says that it is acceptable for anyone to come to his wedding, it is not obligatory for you to come there.

---

Sources:

-https://islamqa.org/hanafi/askimam/5196

-http://www.islaamnet.com/musicharam.html

-http://www.islamawareness.net/Music/prohibited.html

-https://islamqa.info/en/5000

-http://www.imranhosein.org/faq/59-general/224-is-music-allowed-in-islam.html

-https://islamqa.info/en/22006

-http://eshaykh.com/halal_haram/attending-a-non-muslim-wedding/

Comment: eh ... "end quote" means that you are quoting from a source (I assume islamqa) then we require the source of your quote to be clearly linked and the quotes to be marked to distinguish them from your own words... But this looks like one of your opinions: Again before shouting out answers that are rather useless, sit down and learn, once you gained enough knowledge go ahead it is indeed haram to teach or give advice if you have no knowledge of what you are talking about, Read (17:36). We hope one day to have expert answers on this site, thanks to your contributions, experts will rather avoid us.

Comment: Unbelievable, if you could go to site you could see that I was right, ok? And tell me if I’m right.

Comment: To which site? You haven't yet added any link nor edited your answer and I'm sure that the answer on islamqa is certainly a "**no**" as if any of the possible evil things will even appear they wouldn't allow this so the "yes", even if mentioned is a weak yes bound to many conditions which certainly wouldn't apply in a real life situation (even in some Muslim weddings).

Comment: @Medi1Saif Oh, I forgot But I have made like a story, borrowing some informations here and there and voila

Comment: @Medi1Saif But I’ll correct it when I’ll go home, because right now I have to go to school.

Comment: Are you sure you understand, what I try to tell you or do you understand English at all? When you say "End quote" then this means -for the reader- that what you have written before is not your own words and comes from a quoted source, which you haven't done at all. If it is your own statement then delete it, as it is meaningless, else mark it and add the source inside the marked space.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Of course is not my statement...

Comment: @Medi1Saif I do not make up things. I read then, I answer...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69911/discussion-between-medi1saif-and-alex-a).

Comment: @Medi1Saif I was thinking about what you said, and I have edited. Is it good answer now?